# Is there any situation that Neural Network has 100% accuracy but not by an RBF SVM?

Tags: neural-network, classification, svm

There are many examples that `RBF SVM` is better than `Neural Network`.

But Is there any 2D data with two classes that can be discovered with 100% accuracy by a `Neural Network` but not by an `RBF SVM` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: What do you mean by “accuracy”, train accuracy or test accuracy? If you mean the former one then no, as theoretically, RBF can always have 0 train error.

Comment: @VitoChou Test or train is not important. We can assume that train and test are similar (for example XOR data).

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned, the data you use to generate predict model is called the training data, and the train-accuracy is how accurate the model is on this training data.

On the other hand, when future data comes (namely the testing data), the test-accuracy means how accurate the model, depending on the training data only, is on this testing data.

In your case, I suppose you mean the training-accuracy. Then no, [RBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) can always have 100% accuracy [theoretically](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/limit.pdf) when we adjust sigma->0 and C be a sufficient large value.

You can try this on [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/index.html).

```
$ ./svm-train -c 100 -g 100 heart_scale # here g is 1/sigma^2 hence we want a large g
..*
optimization finished, #iter = 790
nu = 0.009851
obj = -132.989193, rho = 0.108246
nSV = 270, nBSV = 0
Total nSV = 270

$ ./svm-predict heart_scale heart_scale.model o
Accuracy = 100% (270/270) (classification)
```